# Excel Custom Task Pane VSTO won't show scroll bar - cannot access UI elements

Tags: winforms, vsto

I have been unable to make a Custom Task Pane display a scroll bar even though there are UI elements not fully displayed

The image below shows the result even after applying the code sample. Note that AutoScroll is set to true

```
        TFSAdminWindow = new TFS_Configuration_UI_Control();

        AdminControl = new TFSAdminControl();

        AdminControl.AutoScroll = true;

        TFSCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(AdminControl, "Configuration Options");


        TFSCustomTaskPane.Control.AutoScroll = true;


        TFSCustomTaskPane.VisibleChanged += ChangeVis;

        TFSCustomTaskPane.DockPosition =
                Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionLeft;
```

[image: Showing no scroll bar]

[image: User Control]

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how the user control is created and consists of. But I'd suggest using any container control where you could put your controls and which could display a scroll bar automatically if required. Also don't forget to set the `Height` and `Width` properties of the task pane.

Comment: I've added a screen shot of the user control editor (to answer your question on how it was created). What it consists of are three check box lists, as in the screen above. I mentioned earlier I had already set Auto Scroll to True. It's not possible to set the Height for a task pane which has the docking set to left or right